# Change text from UIImagePicker buttons

Tags: ios

I have got an app with camera function. When the camera opens, there are 2 buttons. "Retake" to make a new phone and "Use Photo" to use the taken photo. How can I change the text of these buttons?

Comment: Are the buttons `UIButton`?

Comment: i can´t say it. I´am using this `UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];` to open the camera function. inside there are the buttons i want to change

Comment: I found the problem. With localization is everything working.